# create custom shortcode from special mail tags - contact form 7 and International telephone input for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I have currently installed International telephone input for contact form 7 which allows special mail tags to be displayed according to country code or phone number to be displayed. However, It displays the result only in email but can't I can't display the result in posts / pages. So, I think we need to register a custom shortcode which can display the result from it. But have no idea regarding it.

Here is the code from International Telephone Input for WordPress which adds the special tags:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'wpcf7_intl_tel_special_mail_tags', 10, 3 );
function wpcf7_intl_tel_special_mail_tags( $output, $name, $html ) {
if ( wpcf7_intl_tel_ends_with($name, '-cf7it-national') ):
return wpcf7_intl_tel_recover_field( $name );
}

function wpcf7_intl_tel_recover_field ($name){
$value = isset( $_POST[$name] )? trim( wp_unslash( strtr( (string) $_POST[$name], "\n", " " ) ) ) : '';
return $value;
}

function wpcf7_intl_tel_ends_with ($content, $token){
$length = strlen($token);
 return substr($content, -1*$length) == $token;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here are all the hooks for contact form 7 : http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/hooks/#index=c . I think you need to use the hook `wpcf7_form_tag` and then filter the tag name.

Comment: Thanks @DanielVisser for the comment. Does this hook scans and filters the tags?

Comment: I think so, but i'm not 100% sure. I don't have time to check now.